# Skip Page footer on some pages in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Can I skip page footer on some pages (eg. last page)?

```
sub BeforePrint()
    currentpage=.CurrentPage
    lastpage=.pages.count
    if Lastpage=currentpage then
        .Leftfooter=Hidden
    end if
end sub
```

Is there something like the code above in vba?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Each Sheet can have different First Page footer and/or different odd pages footers, but not different last page footer.

[image]
<sub>(source: [contextures.com](http://blog.contextures.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/headeroptions.png))</sub>

You can move the page to a separate sheet or print all other pages separate, clear the footers, print the last page, and then restore the footers.